# Some times getting error of "can not find TTF TrueType font file" for mPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I am getting error in creating pdf using mPDF. I have tried all answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460604/mpdf-cannot-find-ttf-truetype-font-file). Still I am getting below error.

> mPDF Error - cannot find TTF TrueType font file -
>   /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/application/libraries/mpdf60/ttfonts/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf

This path seems perfect. And I have also added DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf in ttfonts folder.

I am defining `_MPDF_PATH` as

```
if (!defined('_MPDF_PATH')) define('_MPDF_PATH', dirname(preg_replace('/\\\\/','/',__FILE__)) . '/');
```

**FYI**: I am not getting this error every time in some cases I am getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after long digging I found solution to add all listed fonts available in [gituhb](https://github.com/rathodakshay/mpdf/tree/development/ttfonts) to the sever. Hope someone will get help through this.